# Android - NullPointerException with popup window

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I have a pop up window in my application and once I got the following `NullPointerException` while testing. But my code is nowhere in the stack trace.

```
/dalvikvm(15212): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409f71f8)
E/AndroidRuntime(15212): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(15212): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(15212):    at android.view.View.onDetachedFromWindow(View.java:9709)
E/AndroidRuntime(15212):    at android.widget.TextView.onDetachedFromWindow(TextView.java:4492)
E/AndroidRuntime(15212):    at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:9818)
E/AndroidRuntime(15212):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2266)
E/AndroidRuntime(15212):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2266)
E/AndroidRuntime(15212):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:2248)
E/AndroidRuntime(15212):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:3707)
E/AndroidRuntime(15212):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2584)
E/AndroidRuntime(15212):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(15212):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(15212):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/AndroidRuntime(15212):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(15212):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(15212):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime(15212):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime(15212):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager( 1195):   Force finishing activity com.android.contacts/.activities.PeopleActivity
```

Can anyone help me find the root cause?

Comment: An exception on [View.java:9709](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#L9709) indicates that somehow, the view attach info's `mHandler` was `null`. The interesting thing is that `mHandler` is declared `final`, so wherever the bad `View.AttachInfo` instance was created, it was constructed with a `null` `Handler`. To catch the problem should it happen again, perhaps you can set a conditional breakpoint on the `View.AttachInfo` constructor (condition: `handler == null`).

Comment: without some code we can nothing to solve. sorry

Answer (score 0):

You might be calling finish() before your pop window is displayed i.e. before it gets attached to your window. Cross check where you are calling finish() for your PeopleActivity.